# How to run specific test class basis system property 'environment'?

Tags: java, jenkins, testing, junit, smoke-testing

Consider different set of smoke tests to be run in `test` and `prod` environments. I've configured the build to hit respective profile to run smoke tests. This build provides the `environment` as parameter. Is there a way to trigger correct Tests (for example ex: one out of `SmokeTestEnvTests.java` and `SmokeProdEnvTests.java`) using this environment system property?

Answer (score 3):

In JUnit4 you can use [Categories](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.html) and execute all Tests of 1..n Categories with the [maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html) (see Using JUnit Categories).

Comment: I went with enclosed option with parameterized.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy should use different [ActiveProfiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html) for different tests classes

> annotation that is used to declare which active bean definition profiles should be used when loading an ApplicationContext for test classes.